# Building two different Android apps that differ only by manifest

Tags: android

I need to create two different Android apps using the same code. The user should be able to install both the apps on the same device.

The differences between the two apps are just a few strings, including the application name. These strings have been isolated to a string resource file called Custom.xml.

My plan to achieve two versions is rather simple. In the nightly build script:

```
1. Run Ant to create the first application .apk file.
2. Rename the generated .apk file
3. Replace Custom.xml with a different one
4. Run Ant once again
```

This may work except for one thing that I am not sure about. It is the package name in AndroidManifest.xml->manifest->package attribute. I guess this has to be different if the apps have to coexist. Does changing the package name have any impact on the rest of the code? I hope this package name is not tied to the package name used in java files.

Also, does anyone see any problem with my overall strategy? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not have any impact, unless you use your hardcoded package name in the code.

There is an [official example of renaming the package](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types) to build a debuggable version of the app.

Comment: Yup. And even if it did copying the project -> changing some package names -> building the new app wouldn't take **so long**.

Comment: I don't think you even have to change the internal package name, I'm pretty sure its only the public one defined in the AndroidManifest